# Using MixedRealityToolkit-Unity to send byte array in Custom Message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, swig, hololens

I'm developing a shared application for the HoloLens and am trying to send an array of bytes using the `Custom Messages.cs` script contained in the [MixedRealityToolkit-Unity](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity).

The repository comes with read/write functionalities for `byte`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `short`, and `Xstring` in the `NetworkConnection.[Write/Read]()` overloaded function, but I can't get the `NetworkMessage.ReadArray()` to return a byte array. It's listed as a void function, which doesn't make any sense, and I don't know how to change it in the SWIG files.

I'm successfully sending many other custom messages over the network, so I know the network connection shouldn't be the problem.

---

#### Writing Message

```
public void SendByteArray(byte[] array)
{
    // If connected to session, broadcast command
    if (serverConnection != null && serverConnection.IsConnected())
    {
        // Create an outgoing network message to contain all the info we want to send
        NetworkOutMessage msg = CreateMessage((byte)TestMessageID.SendArray);

        // Append Command
        msg.WriteArray(array, Convert.ToUInt32(array.Length));

        // Send the message as a broadcast, which will cause the server to forward it to all other users in the session.
        serverConnection.Broadcast(
        msg,
        MessagePriority.Immediate,
        MessageReliability.UnreliableSequenced,
        MessageChannel.Avatar);
    }
}
```

#### Receiving Message

```
private byte[] OnArrayReceived(NetworkInMessage msg)
{
    msg.ReadInt64(); // need to read UserID first, but isn't used for this function
    return msg.ReadArray();
}
```

Based on the signature, it looks like it's a poorly copied and renamed writing function, but I don't know how to modify it.

```
public virtual void ReadArray(byte[] data, uint arrayLength) {
    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle pinHandle_data = global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(data, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned); try {
    {
      SharingClientPINVOKE.NetworkInMessage_ReadArray(swigCPtr, (global::System.IntPtr)pinHandle_data.AddrOfPinnedObject(), arrayLength);
    }
    } finally { pinHandle_data.Free(); }
}
```

Here's the definition for `NetworkInMessage_ReadArray()`

but it comes with this warning.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated />
//
// This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
// Version 3.0.10
//
// Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
// the SWIG interface file instead.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answering - All the project files you should need are contained in the repo (linked above) under the test section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is returning back a point to an array.  So one of the two methods should work.  You need to allocate an array large enough to return all the data.  I made the array 1024 buyt you can make any size.  I'm not sure seeing the code If the array has to be in managed or unmanaged memory space.  So 1st method uses Managed memory and 2nd unmanaged.

```
        const uint BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private byte[] OnArrayReceived(NetworkInMessage msg)
        {
            msg.ReadInt64(); // need to read UserID first, but isn't used for this function
            // method 1
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            ReadArray(ref data, BUFFER_SIZE);
            return data;

            //method 2
            IntPtr dataptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(BUFFER_SIZE);
            ReadArray2(dataptr, BUFFER_SIZE);

            byte[] data2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            Marshal.Copy(dataptr, data2, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataptr);
            return data2;
        }

        public void ReadArray(ref byte[] data, uint length)
        {
        }
        public void ReadArray2(IntPtr data, uint length)
        {
        }
```